# How to monitor for incoming file transfer requests on Android Wifi Direct (P2P)

Tags: android, sockets, p2p

I currently have an application that sends a string from one device to another.
I monitor for this initial file transfer by opening the port on device connection to the group owner, the client then sends the file and the group owner receives it no problem. The socket closes.

If however the client tries to send a second file the socket has been closed, the connection state has not changed so I cannot think of a way to have the GO reopen the socket for this second transfer. Any suggestions?

Initial opening of the socket.

```
if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
            FileServerAsyncTask at = new FileServerAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());
            at.execute();
}
```

The File transfers async task:

```
public class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    private Context context;

    public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2553);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            String[] message = getMessage(client);
            serverSocket.close();
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //  Error message.
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            //  Do something with result.
        }

    }
}
```

And for completeness the way I get my message out:

```
public static String[] getMessage(Socket s)
        throws IOException {

    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    int len = is.available();
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    String msg = new String(buffer);

    String[] myMessageArray = msg.split(",");
    return myMessageArray;
}
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: why not keep the server socket open?

Comment: I was under the impression leaving an open socket was bad practice. This perhaps would indeed work but I hadn't considered it. So this opens up a follow up question.

If the socket was left open how would I listen to it to grab the incoming message?

Comment: Check my updated answer. The server needs to keep listening to a socket since you never know when the client wants to connect to it. So when it does, it runs another thread to handle the client while it is always listening to other connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to have the server socket always listening to connections. And when it accepts one, it will run it in a different thread

```
  while (true) {
         Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
         new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(socket)).start();
      }
```

The MultiThreadServer will do what ever you want to do with the Client and then it will close the socket on which it was connected to the client. Note that this is a different socket than the one the server is listening to in the while loop.

Check this for more infos on multithreaded servers: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/net_multisoc.htm

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer so that others will benefit from it!